# Ban failed pure-ftpd login attempts using iptables

Tags: iptables, ftp

Just curious if there is a way to block IPs after 3 failed login attempts to pure-ftpd, but only for a couple of hours, strictly using iptables.  I have heard using fail2ban works fine for this, but am curious if you can do it just by using iptables.

Thanks

Comment: iptables is a firewall, not a log parser.

Comment: I saw this command used elsewhere on the internet: iptables -I INPUT -p TCP -m state --state NEW -m limit \
--limit 30/minute --limit -burst 5 -j ACCEPT

Comment: That's rate limiting and isn't even relevant to this question.

Comment: Thanks, in other words it prevents the user from logging in multiple times in a row?  Only once per 30 min?  or 5 per 30 min?  Sorry I have looked for documentation on this but couldn't find it.

Comment: You need to spend some time doing research. Google the term "rate limiting". Read [the `fail2ban` documentation](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8) and understand what it does (and why that is fundamentally different from connection rate limiting).

Comment: Actually the term rate limiting seems rather self explanatory, doesn't it?  Perhaps I should have rephrased the question to "best preventative measures from brute force login attempts to pure-ftpd using iptables".  Anyway, the comments have sort of helped me realize the fundamental difference.  I guess I'll go do some more research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you cannot do that using iptables only.**

[Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) will do exactly what you want, possibly (it's configurable) through iptables.

By itself, however, iptables is only a firewall, stateful if you want it to be but still nothing more than a firewall. You can set up rate limiting rules for new connections, but that's about as close as you can get without a log parser or some other mechanism to react to events that take place in the software you want to monitor. And because of the impact of any possible bugs, you probably wouldn't want to run that sort of thing in kernel space anyway (rather than crashing the log parser application, it runs a serious risk of bringing down the entire operating system).

Comment: This sums up the conversation above and is what I needed to know.  I already read some of the fail2ban documentation and realized that's probably my best bet going forward.  But are you suggesting that rate limiting is more demanding on the server than fail2ban?

Comment: No, log parsing is almost certainly more computationally heavy unless you're doing something like running a core router. What matters is the impact of a bug. And comments are supposed to be ephemeral and are meant primarily for asking for clarification and suggesting improvements, which is why I decided to write up an answer to actually answer your question.